# Response body missing characters

Tags: iis, httpresponse

I've seen this issue happen on multiple machines, using different languages and server-side environments. It seems to always be IIS, but it may be more widespread.

On slower connections, characters are occasionally missing from the response body. It happens somewhere between 25% and 50% of the time but only on certain pages, and only on a slow connection such as VPN. A refresh usually fixes the issue.

The current application in question is .NET 4 with SQL Server.

Example:

```
<script>
  document.write('Something');
</script>
```

is being received by the client as

```
<scrit>
  document.write('Something');
</script>
```

This causes the JavaScript inside the tag to instead be printed to the page, rather than executing.

Does anyone know why this occurs? Is it specific to IIS?

Comment: For those who don't wish to play "spot the difference", the opening `<script>` tag is missing a `p`.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not quite awake enough to realize that was ambiguous

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Speaking generally, the problem you describe would require corruption at the HTTP layer or above, since TCP/IP has checksums, packet lengths, sequence numbers, and re-transmissions to avoid this sort of issue.

That leaves:

- The application generating the data
- Any intermediate filters between the application and the server
- The HTTP server returning the data
- Any intermediary HTTP proxies, transparent or otherwise
- The HTTP client requesting the data
- The user-agent interpreting the data

You can diagnose further based off of a network capture performed at the server edge, and at the client edge.

- Examine the request made by the client at the client edge to verify that the client is making a request for the entire document, and is not relying upon cache (no `Range` or `If-*` headers).
- If the data is correct when it leaves the server (pay particular attention to the `Content-Length` header and verify it is a `200` response), neither the server nor the application are at fault.
- If the data is correct as received by the client, you can rule out intermediary proxies.
- If there is still an issue, it is a user-agent issue

If I had to psychically debug such a problem, I would look first at the application to ensure it is generating the correct document, then assume some interloper is modifying the data in transit.  (Some HTTP proxy for wan-acceleration, aggressive caching, virus scanning, etc...)  I might also assume some browser plugin or ad blocker is modifying the response after it is received.

I would not, however, assume it is the HTTP server without very strong evidence. If corruption is detected on the client, but not the server, I might disable TCP Offload and look for an updated NIC Driver.